# Get name of all available classes under model.tt : Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, complextype

I want to get all available classes name those are listed under Model.tt.

I have tried below piece of code to get them but that is giving only table name not complex types which are imported via stored procedure:

```
var x = ((IObjectContextAdapter)d).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.CSpace); // d is my context object.
```

I have tried all available options of `DataSpace enum` with no luck.

Above code only returns table name like `Employee`, `Department` but I want to get complex types as well like `USP_GetDepartments_Result`, `USP_GetAllEmployee_Result` which are complex types generated from stored procedure.

I am using EntityFrameWork version 6. I have searched on `StackOverflow` but did not get result related to stored procedure part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got my result by below line of code:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)d).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(DataSpace.CSpace)
```

Its giving me all the types of object context. Then I filtered them and got complex types.